# Nodejs async await function JSON

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have a little probleme. I want send in my res.json in classes: postQuery.room. But it's send in classes: undefined, why?

**ROUTE GET**

```
app.get('/', async function (req, res) {
   const pageSize = +req.query.pagesize;
   const page = +req.query.page;
   if (pageSize && page) {
       postQuery = await Classe.find({}).skip(pageSize * (page - 1)).limit(pageSize);
   }
   const nbClasses = await Classe.count({});
   res.json({ success: true, message: "Classes fetched successfully!", classes: postQuery.room, total: nbClasses });
});
```

**postQuery return if I use in res.json => classes: postQuery**

```
{
   "success": true,
   "message": "Classes fetched successfully!",
   "classes": [
       {
           "_id": "5bfd26072b9d9c33005b58c2",
           "room": "NodeJs",
           "createdAt": "2018-11-27T11:09:59.077Z",
           "updatedAt": "2018-11-27T11:09:59.077Z",
           "__v": 0
       }
   ],
   "total": 11
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the JSON you expect?

Comment: {
    "success": true,
    "message": "Classes fetched successfully!",
    "classes": [
        "NodeJs"
    ],
    "total": 11
}

Answer (score 3):

I think you've missed that

```
await Classe.find(...)...
```

returns an array, note the square brackets in your response. What may be helpful is:

```
{..., classes: postQuery.map(a=>a.room), ...}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I try this and it's work, it's worj with await Classe.find({})